# Generic USB Mass Media Drivers getting in the way of drivers for ADB

Tags: android, windows, adb, driver

I was able to install the correct Android drivers on my Windows system so that it synced up with adb and the Android SDK and I was able to run and debug programs on it through Eclipse and Android Studio.  It was going fine for a week or so but today my device will only be recognized as a "USB Mass Media Storage" device and will not be recognized by adb.  (I'm sure something was changed, but I have no idea what.)

-Whenever I try to reinstall the drivers that were working before I get "The best driver software for your device is already installed."  Whenever I uninstall the driver, the computer immediately reinstalls the Mass Media Storage drivers before I have any time to react even though I have disabled automatic driver updating (or at least the option in System menu). By choosing the "Let me pick from a list of drivers" option and browsing to the driver's .inf it will let me install it as either an ADB Interface or a Composite ADB Interface, but though it claims to install successfully, nothing works; ADB never finds a device, the device never says that anything is asking for debug permision (like it did before).  And considering that before both interfaces were shown in the Device Manager, I'm confident the driver isn't being installed correctly.

I feel as though there is a corrupt driver or registry that I need to delete but I have no idea how I'd locate it.

- I've tried revoking USB debuggin authorization, then wiping the cache partition in my device, then restoring it to factory settings to no effect.
- Yes, the USB debugging option has been on the whole time.

Comment: Why do you mention ADK in the title?  Your question seems to be purely about ADB (or more specifically, Windows), not the Accessory Development Kit.

Comment: Sorry, got confused about the terminology.  I fixed the title.

Comment: What is your device? I had this problem with a Nexus 5 and searched for a while. the problem was I wasn't using the cable the phone came with...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently even though the developer options were still visible, I had somehow ceased being a developer on my phone.  The solution was to reinstate developer mode by tapping the build number 7 times.